# Crystal Reports Suppress a field with suppress formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi I'm using Crystal Report 2008, and this is the scenario:

```
  ITEM No.           Product            Pcs       Status (this Status field is hidden)
  -------------------------------------------------------
  1                 Product1           2030       Cancelled  
  2                 Product2           1000       Cancelled
  3                 Product3           5000       Ok
  4                 Product4           3000       Cancelled
  5                 Product5           4000       Ok
```

Now how can I suppress in the Details/group section by formula all of the Status is "Cancelled" and the output should be like this:

```
  ITEM No.           Product            Pcs       Status (this Status field is hidden)
  -------------------------------------------------------
  1                 Product3           5000       Ok
  2                 Product5           4000       Ok
```

Comment: What's wrong with just adding this suppression formula to the section? `{Table.Status}='Cancelled'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

1. On the Section Expert, Suppress (No Drill-down) enter `Status =
   'Cancelled'`.
2. Add a parameter for Status (OK, Cancelled, All) so that you can filter the records as per the selection.

Comment: But how about the number? how can I make it reset if the line is suppressed?